# load clr library with native dependencies

Tags: c++, dependencies, c++-cli, clr, ironpython

I'm scripting IronPython and trying to load a library I wrote that uses CLI/C++ to interop with native C++.  Is there a way to get IronPython to load the CLR library and find the appropriate native libraries given that I can't directly add references to non-CLR libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that IronPython won't find all system files on its own.  I used [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find the system dlls I was missing.